# Bash "virtual" prefix terminal

Tags: bash

I am setting up firewall using firewall-cmd but it takes lots of time just to type firewall-cmd all the time.

It is possible to create temporary "virtual" shell or something which will append firewall-cmd to each following inputs ?

Example :

```
$ coolcommand firewall-cmd
> --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
[.....]
> --add-service https
> ^C
$
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use alias? `alias fwc='firewall-cmd'` and then you have only three letters to type.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a GNU way to do it instead of having to create aliases for each purpose

Answer (score 0):

A loop with `eval`, like this:

```
coolcommand () { while IFS= read -rep "> $1 " line; do eval "$1 $line"; done; }
```

Then invoke `coolcommand firewall-cmd` like in your example.

Note `firewall-cmd`  gets "glued" to the beginning of every line you type, but it's still the shell who evaluates the resulting string. So  `$`, `*`, `;`, `#`, quotes or such are still special. In particular after `coolcommand firewall-cmd`, typing `--list-all; date` will run `firewall-cmd --list-all` and `date` (not `firewall-cmd date`).

---

Improvements for better experience:

- It's possible to pass a command with argument(s) as well. Example:

  ```
    coolcommand 'printf "foo %s\n"'
  ```
- The same as a script. Added history support:

  ```
    #!/bin/bash

    unset HISTFILE
    HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

    while IFS= read -rep "> $1 " line; do
       history -s "$line"
       eval "$1 $line"
    done
  ```

The history is not saved when the script is about to exit, still during a single invocation it should work (<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> like normally in Bash).