# How to automatically insert text at the beginning of each bash input line?

Tags: bash

Is there a way to configure `bash` to automatically insert text at the beginning of each input line? For example, to automatically insert the string `'git '` at the beginning of each input line, to save the user from having to repeatedly type `git`. This would allow me to create a very minimal `git` shell, with autocompletion.

Comment: Somewhat similar: [Bash "virtual" prefix terminal](https://superuser.com/q/1494061/432690).

Comment: To shorten, you could create an alias `g` to `git`. You save two key-strokes.

Comment: Or use sed (https://linuxconfig.org/add-character-to-the-beginning-of-each-line-using-sed) or the Kate text editor to search and replace on EOL.

Answer (score 0):

Your <kbd>Enter</kbd> probably sends <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> (confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you should see `^M`), but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> works like <kbd>Enter</kbd> as well.

This allows us to solve your problem with one shell command:

```
bind '"\C-m": "\C-jgit "'
```

Note: with <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> you can still delete the `git`  string and type any command.