# Is it possible to manipulate shell input to wrap commands?

Tags: bash, fish

I would like to call a function when a command is entered and modify it
for example if a user enters this command

```bash
touch foo.txt
```

I want to manipulate it to run

```bash
sudo -u user touch foo.txt
```

The reason is that I as root have a lot of directories belonging to different users that don't have shell access (so I can't just sudo user)
and a lot of times I want to run a command as that user
I would like to write script to check for the current directory owner and run the command as that user.

Thank you.

Comment: like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555622/prefix-all-commands-in-shell ?

Comment: (1) "users that don't have shell access (so I can't just sudo user)" – Please clarify the inside of the parentheses. You can do `sudo -u user touch …`, so maybe you can do `sudo -u user bash`. Does the policy disallow the latter? (2) Regardless of that, you may want a solution that finds the right `user` automatically; but mindlessly modifying each and every command is an invitation for an accident waiting to happen, or at least an inconvenience when you try to use a shell keyword, builtin or `sudo`. An on-demand call like `s touch foo.txt` seems better.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski 1. the users shell is set to `/usr/sbin/nologin`. 2. That could be an option as well

Comment: (1) Does it affect your ability to run `sudo -u user bash`?

Comment: An alternative method is to [find the owner of the current folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7730/find-the-owner-of-a-directory-or-file-but-only-return-that-and-nothing-else) and `su` as that user, do your work, finally exit `su`.

Comment: The title is kinda [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). IMO it should be "How can I make my shell run commands as the owner of the current directory automatically?" or so. Is it OK with you if we change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Preliminary note

The question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and [fish](/questions/tagged/fish). This answer is for `bash`. I don't know `fish` at all.

---

#### On-demand solution

> users that don't have shell access (so I can't just sudo user)

You can do `sudo -u user touch …`, so probably you can do `sudo -u user bash`. This may work even for a user whose login shell is `/usr/sbin/nologin` or so. The security policy for `sudo` (usually `sudoers`) is what matters, not the login shell.

Regardless of that, you may want a solution that finds the right user automatically; but mindlessly modifying each and every command is an invitation for an accident waiting to happen, or at least an inconvenience when you try to use a shell keyword, builtin or `sudo`. An on-demand call like `s touch foo.txt` seems better.

This is a shell function for `sh`, `bash` or any POSIX-compliant shell:

```sh
s() (
   user="$(stat -c %U ./)"
   if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
      set bash
   fi
   exec sudo -u "$user" -- "$@"
)
```

Note: The function uses GNU `stat`, it's not portable. [There is no flawless portable way to get the owner of a file though](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7730/108618).

Usage:

- `s touch foo.txt`
- or just `s` to get an interactive Bash. Ultimately use `exit` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> ([twice if needed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/177651/108618)) to return to your main shell.

If you're using bash completion, run `complete -F _command s` to make completions sanely work with `s`.

---

#### Towards a truly automatic solution

There are ways to use `s` (or whatever) for every command line automatically (e.g. [*Bash "virtual" prefix terminal*](https://superuser.com/q/1494061/432690)). Note `s cd …` or `s if …` cannot work, so prepending each and every command line with `s` will most certainly break your workflow.

If you really want to do this automatically then consider an automation that transforms `some command(s)` to `s bash -c 'some command(s)'`. The below solution is based on my answer to [*How can I single-quote or escape the whole command line in Bash conveniently?*](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690)

First define a function that will transform the command line upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>:

```bash
_prepend_s() { READLINE_LINE="s bash -c ${READLINE_LINE@Q}"; }
bind -x '"\C-x\C-o":_prepend_s'
```

In my Kubuntu <kbd>Enter</kbd> gets to Bash as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> is equivalent. Quite convenient, as now we can do:

```bash
bind '"\C-m":"\C-x\C-o\C-j"'
```

and from now on <kbd>Enter</kbd> will transform `some command(s)` to `s bash -c 'some command(s)'` and execute the result automatically. This will support `cd`, multiple commands (with `;`, `&&`, `||`), pipelines, `if …` and such, but not multi-line code (unless the code gets pasted when [`enable-bracketed-paste`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html#index-enable_002dbracketed_002dpaste) is `on` (see `bind -v | grep enable-bracketed-paste`)). You need to remember that:

- the typed line gets passed to a separate shell and thus cannot affect your current shell (e.g. `cd ~; pwd` will work as expected, but the current working directory of *your* interactive shell will not be affected);
- each invocation is standalone (e.g. `foo=bar` <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then `echo "$foo"` <kbd>Enter</kbd> will not show you `bar`);
- nothing will be expanded by your current shell (unless you request this beforehand, i.e. while typing, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> or so);
- actions while typing (e.g. completions) will work in your current shell and there is no guarantee it would work the same way in the other user's interactive shell.

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the command line directly in your current shell, as your current user.

There is a downside of this simple approach: the command is stored in history as `s bash -c …` and if you want to repeat it by <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> then it will fail. A quick fix may be:

```bash
_prepend_s() { history -s "$READLINE_LINE"; READLINE_LINE=" s bash -c ${READLINE_LINE@Q}"; }
```

which stores the original command in the history, and the leading space prevents the actual command from being stored (a functionality governed by [`HISTCONTROL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-HISTCONTROL)); there are other approaches to this problem.

---

#### Solution I like

If I were you, I would prefer seeing the full command, including `sudo -u` (so it's clear what user it run as); and I would want to keep the original functionality of <kbd>Enter</kbd> (to avoid surprises). This is what I would use:

```bash
# IMPORTANT: do it in a fresh shell, so our previous bindings don't interfere
_act_as_dirowner() {
   history -s "$READLINE_LINE"
   local user
   user="$(stat -c %U ./)"
   [ "$user" != "$USER" ] && READLINE_LINE=" sudo -u $user bash -c ${READLINE_LINE@Q}";
}
bind -x '"\C-x\C-o":_act_as_dirowner'
bind '"\C-j":"\C-x\C-o\C-m"'
```

Now:

- <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> executes the command line normally;
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> injects `sudo -u … bash -c` if needed (i.e. if the owner of the current working directory is not you).

Notes:

- Any value of `$user` should be safe if embedded in a command line verbatim (I mean we don't need `${user@Q}`).
- GNU `stat -c %U ./` returns `UNKNOWN` if the directory is owned by UID that has no name; you may want to build some additional logic to catch this.
- You can still use our function `s` independently on demand, e.g.:

  - `… | …` <kbd>Enter</kbd> will execute everything as you;
  - `… | …` <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will execute everything as the owner of the current working directory;
  - `… | s …` <kbd>Enter</kbd> will execute the first part of the pipeline as you, the second part (after `s`) as the owner of the directory.
- Multi-line commands may be troublesome. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> may misbehave if used with a multi-line command with unbalanced quoting. And I admit I have managed to crash Bash 5.2.15 by using our <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on a multi-line command with balanced quoting.

Adjust the solution to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response,  this solutions works, however i loose autocompletion with this, can this function support autocompletion somehow? thank you

Comment: @phper `complete -F _command s`

Comment: Thank you so much for your very details response, I very much like your liked solution. I implemented it and it works very nice